# smartphone pentest framework

Tags: penetration-test

I have done some searching around Google to find out if there are any penetration testing frameworks like metasploit on Backtrack for computers and its applications

Can any one help me to find such for mobiles.

Thanks,
Neo

Comment: metasploit is an exploitation framework,  not a penetrationTESTing framework.  The difference is as a pentester I find exploits that eventually make it into metasploit...

Comment: OK Rook , Can you let me know any tools/framework which i can use for mobiles

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but you could try Oxygen Forensic (http://www.oxygen-forensic.com/en/). It's a powerful tool and it have a very complete trial version.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just install Linux (Kali) and run from that, but still you would need more for serious testing.

You can give dSploit a look, I myself am not a fan. But it seems to work, also you can try VulnDisco Mobile for CANVAS but it is quite a pricey product.